# Device stuck in a "bootloop". Resolved after re-inserting battery

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

A Customer of mine has a Casio V-T500 Tablet on which he runs our app. For a few days it started to be stuck in a bootloop which could be broken by removing the battery, wait a few seconds, and then putting the battery back and starting the device. It's running Android 4.0.4 with an special Launcher by Casio.

Does someone ever have/had this kind of problem? How can this be resolved? Is this a hardware failure? After about 9 Months of "work"?

Comment: Removing battery is called hard-reboot. Hard rebooting is different than soft-rebooting, so there's a difference in the process you perform. Why is it happening? I can't tell but seems pretty much software related. You can try to backup your phone and try a wipe to see if it is a fix.

Comment: As I have no physical access to this or any similar device, it will be hard for me to guess what the user has to do in order to backup and wipe the device. It would be enough for me to know, if something like this can happen by installing an app, or if this is something that is hardware related.

Comment: Oh, I thought you had the phone in your hands. Well one can't tell without examining of course. If the phone is not rooted, and if the problem is not caused right after an OS update, then a factory reset would be enough to tell if problem is caused by software or hardware.

Comment: So, if this problem still exists after a factory reset, it's most likely a hardware failure?

Comment: Yes. If the phone is used only the way it is meant to be.

Comment: Putting it in and out of a dockingstation should be a valid use case ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck in a similar bootloop last Sunday on my Samsung GS4 (i9505G), except instead of rebooting, it would power off.  Pulling the battery did not resolve it.  I had to plug it in to a charger.  The battery was at about 25% at the time.

Sadly, I do not know why that resolved the problem, but I wanted to post my reply in case it helps someone.